# Change username in Fortify Audit Workbench

Tags: fortify

I'm using Fortify 17.20 Audit Workbench. I'd like to change the username it uses to state I left a comment. It currently uses my Microsoft username, but I want it to use a different name.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that grab your current user, can you use the "run as" option.